# Is my platy still pregnant?

Tags: aquarium, fish, community-aquarium, pregnancy, reproduction

First time trying to keep fry alive here so have been keeping an eye on this mummy fish.
A few days ago she looked alot "rounder" now she appears a little flat? I'm aware they get a boxy look but I'm thinking maybe I have missed the birth this time round? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Platy fish pregnant](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10196/platy-fish-pregnant)

Comment: To ensure the fry to be alive, you can add a box to the tank, walls made from fine web (i.e. tights like women wear them, at a boxlike shape made of chopsticks or similar) and trap the mother fish inside. After she gave birth you can free her and when the fry is big enough you free them too